# Adjective to describe something that tastes unpleasant because it has too many flavors?

Tags: single-word-requests

How would you call something that tastes sweet, salty, sour, all at the same time? And in an unpleasant way?

Example:

> I didn't like her cake. I didn't like its [...] taste.

I could only think of the word *over-complicated*, but I think it doesn't fits food very well. Maybe *muddled*?

Comment: You could always go with a slightly sarcastic expression: "*This cake is **way** too complex for my palate*."

Comment: Are you really looking for a *verb* (in the title) or an adjective (in your fill-in-the-blank)?

Comment: You might refer to a *cacophony of [competing] flavors*

Comment: I've heard of dishes that are a jumble of flavors referred to (especially on cooking shows) as [_muddled_](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/muddle).

Comment: @Jim Oh, you're right. I meant adjective.

Comment: *goulash*; *hodgepodge* (also, *hotchpotch*); *mashup;* ...

Comment: I would call it a ***grapefruit***.

Comment: As Kris mentions there are lots of nouns for foods with many things mixed in indiscriminately: also mish-mash, dog's-dinner, jumble, mess, medley, and less food-related terms like farrago. But not many adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If its sweet, salty, sour, all at the same time.
>
> **assorted**
> adj
>
> consisting of various kinds mixed together; miscellaneous: assorted
> sweets.

- I didn't like her cake. I didn't like its [**assorted**] tastes.

Comment: Assorted requires a plural noun: *I didn't like its assorted **tastes***

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use any negative adjective and then add explanation.
 *I didn't like its **foul** taste because it was sweet, salty and sour at the same time.*

Answer (score 1):

‘Overwhelming to the senses’. Meaning that there’s just too much going on.

http://www.emsherif.com/“overwhelming-senses-and-unique-culinary-experience”-“epitomised-joy-food”

I suppose it depends what you’re expecting - the link recommends you ‘Brace your taste-buds for an onslaught...!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any word that specifically means simultaneously sweet, salty and sour.

The general term that comes to mind for food is *overseasoned.*  However, this is a bit strange to you with cake, since you don't "season" it.  One option would be say *over-flavor*.  (Still, sour cake?!?  I think in the context of cake, saying "This case is too sour" is a perfectly good quip.)

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there *is* a word for what you are trying to describe: the one that most closely describes the complex mix of flavours you mentioned is probably [*umami,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umami) but that is a term for a *pleasant* savoury flavour.

The reason for the lack of such a word is probably that — except in the relatively unusual context of being taught how to cook — few people expend much effort on analysing precisely *in what way* what they're eating tastes terrible.

For most, it's normally enough to say "This tastes awful!"; maybe *some* might even exclaim "Too much salt!"

Comment: *Umami* is a different flavor from salty, sour, sweet and bitter, that is also sensed by the tastebuds. It's not a combination.